# How many ALU operations can run in parallel on modern x86_64?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture

How many ALU operations can run in parallel on modern x86(_64) CPUs when each instruction has no dependency to others? It would obviously depend on a specific model, but then, where can I find such information? [This wikipedia page of Sandy Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandy_Bridge) says it has 3 integer ALUs per core. Does this mean it can run 3 integer arithmetic instructions at the same time?

---

My question is about such code, for example,

```
add r10, r11
mov [...], r10
add r12, r13
mov [...], r12
add r14, r15
mov [...], r14

add rax, r11
mov [...], rax
add rax, r13
mov [...], rax
add rax, r15
mov [...], rax
```

I may be wrong, but my understanding is that the first 3 `add`s can run in parallel while the following `add`s have to wait until the previous operations have finished.

Comment: See https://uops.info/ for exact details on throughput and latency.  (And https://agner.org/optimize/ for pipeline details relevant to getting more un-executed uops into the scheduler(s), especially on AMD CPUs where integer and FP/SIMD ALUs have separate ports and schedulers so after a cache miss, you might have 8 uops all dispatch to ports at once.) Also related [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44169342) re: `mov` taking an execution unit or not on SnB vs. IvB where there are fewer integer ALUs than sustained front-end bandwidth

Comment: Intel Alder Lake has even wider cores, like 5 ALU ports and a front-end that can keep up, on the P-cores. Even the E-cores have 4/clock throughput for `add`, like earlier mainstream performance cores such as Ice Lake and Zen3.

Comment: But yes, if those 5 `add` and `mov` instruction were all in the scheduler at once on SnB when `r10..r15` became ready, those 3 `add` instructions would dispatch in parallel if there weren't older uops waiting to run ([How are x86 uops scheduled, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40681331)).  The front-end (issue/rename) on SnB is only 4-wide, so if this instruction sequence was getting issued after an I-cache miss or an `lfence` or something, only the first 4 uops could get into the back-end in the first cycle.